# GitPython `repo.index.commit()` spawns persistent git.exe instance, holds handles to repo

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to use GitPython for some repo manipulation, but ran into issues with my app, with handles open where i wouldn't expect.

Bug-jarring the issue, it seems that calling `repo.index.commit()` results in a handle to the directory (presumably something in `.git\`).  Later this causes other failures in what my app is trying to do.

Here is a working unittest:

```py
import unittest
import git
import tempfile
import os.path

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def testCreateRepo(self):
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix=(__loader__.name) + "_") as mydir:

            # MAKE NEW REPO 
            repo = git.Repo.init(path=os.path.join(mydir, "newRepo"), mkdir=True)
            self.assertTrue(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(repo.working_dir, ".git")), "Failed to make new repo?")

            # MAKE FILE, COMMIT REPO
            testFileName = "testFile.txt"
            open(os.path.join(repo.working_dir, testFileName) , "w").close()
            repo.index.add([testFileName])
            self.assertTrue(repo.is_dirty())

            #### 
            # COMMENTING THIS OUT --> TEST PASSES
            repo.index.commit("added initial test file") 
            self.assertFalse(repo.is_dirty())
            #### 

            # adding this does not affect the handle
            git.cmd.Git.clear_cache()


            print("done") # exception thrown right after this, on __exit__
```

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\EXAMPLE_gitpython_v3kbrly_\newRepo'

digging a little deeper, it seems that gitPython spawns multiple instances of git.exe processes, and each of them holds a handle to the *root* folder of the repo `newRepo`.

- set a breakpoint immediately before the error, use sysinternals/handle to see open handles to `newRepo` ...  git.exe (4 separate PID's of git.exe to be precise)
- using sysinternals/procexp i can see that that they are all spawned from the eclipse-->python

stepping through, it's the call to repo.index.commit() that actually leads to the the git.exe(s) being spawned.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be getting anywhere, and this seems like bad behavior, so i submitted a bug:  https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with the gitpython devs, I found the answer:

Due to internal caching behavior of gitpython, you must force a garbage collection, and tell the repo to clear it's cache.  I was doing the latter, but on the wrong object.

the following must be added prior to cleaning up your dir (`__exit__()`ing my `with:`/context-manager clause, in the code above)

```
import gc
gc.collect()
repo.git.clear_cache()
```

Those do not seem to obey least-surprise :) hopefully the api can be improved in the future.